# Web App how do I update table after a function

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

ok, so I'm making some progress with my webapp, I initially fetch the table information using:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTable).getTable();
```

The function for that is

```
 function buildTable(myTable) {
    document.getElementById('table_id').innerHTML = myTable;
  }
```

But I have another function which changes the values in the table (that works correctly), but it isn't rerunning the load table function

```
<input type ="button" id="slideL" value="Advance" onclick ="google.script.run.logicAdvance(3).withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)"/>
```

which calls logic advance successfuly (the value changes) but not updateOutput at all

```
function updateOutput(){
Logger.log("Update Output"+info);
document.getElementById('table_id').style.display ='block';
document.getElementById('ask').style.display = "none";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTable).getTable();

}
```

Any ideas?

Update: Ok, I dropped the logger calls and added a with error one, which does not seem to be running either. Current version of code.

```
function updateOutput(result){
document.getElementById('ask').innerHTML = result.displayInfo;
document.getElementById('table_id').style.display ='block';
document.getElementById('ask').style.display = "none";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTable).getTable();


}
function errorFunction (e){
document.getElementById('ask').innerHTML = e;

}

  <div id="ask" style="display:block">Do you want to proceed with this idea?
      <div id="choiceBox">
          <input type ="button" id="slideL" value="Advance" onclick ="google.script.run.logicAdvance(3).withSuccessHandler(updateOutput).withFailureHandler(errorFunction)"/>
          <input type ="button" id="declineButton" value="Decline" onclick ="finish()"/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The result is that this does nothing, neither the success nor the failure functions are updating the content of the "ask" text. Somehow we are wandering off into the wildrenss of the backend and not coming back?

These two functions ARE working, just not returning, I don't think?

```
function logicAdvance(row){

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('row', row);
  var status = ss.getRange(row,9).getValue();
  var myObj ={displayValue : "none"};  

  if (status == 1){myObj.displayValue= "block"; return myObj;}
  if (status == 4){myObj.displayValue= "block"; return myObj;}

  advanceStatus(row);
  return myObj;}

//- This function changes the status of the object
function advanceStatus(row){

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xx');
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var status = ss.getRange(row, 9);
  var newStatus = parseInt(status.getValue()) +  1;
  if (newStatus == 20) return;
  if (newStatus == 9) return;
  status.setValue(newStatus);
  return;
```

Comment: Maybe add a `.withFailureHandler(errorFunctionName)` to your `google.script.run` and then display any error returned?  It is possible your server side is not fully successful.

Comment: I am getting a weird console error: userCodeAppPanel:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'withSuccessHandler' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the command call backward:

```
      <input type ="button" id="slideL" value="Advance" onclick ="google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
.withFailureHandler(errorFunction)
.logicAdvance(3)"/>
```

Fixes it!

Answer (score 1):

There's no `Logger` in html. `info`doesn't seem to be defined either. 
Use `console.info()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, logging to the console is what helped me find the problem that fixed it.